# Spring-Data-Rest Validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-validator

I have been trying to add spring validators to a spring-data-rest project.

I followed along and setup the "getting started" application via this link: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

...and now I am trying to add a custom PeopleValidator by following the documents here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/validation-chapter.html

My custom PeopleValidator looks like

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class PeopleValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        errors.reject("DIE");
    }
}
```

...and my Application.java class now looks like this

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PeopleValidator beforeCreatePeopleValidator() {
        return new PeopleValidator();
    }
}
```

I would expect that POSTing to the `http://localhost:8080/people` URL would result in an error of some kind since the PeopleValidator is rejecting everything. However, no error is thrown, and the validator is never called.

I have also tried manually setting up the validator as shown in section 5.1 of the spring-data-rest documentation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So it appears that the before/after "save" events only fire on PUT and PATCH. When POSTing, the before/after "create" events fire.

I tried it the manual way again using the `configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener` override and it worked. I'm not sure what I'm doing differently at work than here at home. I'll have to look tomorrow.

I sure would love to hear if others have suggestions on why it wouldn't work.

For the record, here is what the new Application.java class looks like.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", new PeopleValidator());
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently the "beforeSave" event does not fire, but the "beforeCreate" event does. I still had to wire it the "manual" way instead of using a bean named "beforeCreatePeopleValidator".

Comment: I am finding the same situation, auto discovery is not working.

Comment: I'm also having a similair issue - manually wiring events is working just fine, automatic discovery fails.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with it not being auto discovered.  I created a JIRA on it: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-524

Comment: Now, you have to extend `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` as `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` version is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the feature is currently not implemented (2.3.0), unluckily there are no constants for the event names otherwise the solution below would not be that fragile.

The `Configuration` adds all properly named `Validator` beans to `ValidatingRepositoryEventListener` using the right event.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Configuration
public class ValidatorRegistrar implements InitializingBean {

    private static final List<String> EVENTS;
    static {
        List<String> events = new ArrayList<String>();
        events.add("beforeCreate");
        events.add("afterCreate");
        events.add("beforeSave");
        events.add("afterSave");
        events.add("beforeLinkSave");
        events.add("afterLinkSave");
        events.add("beforeDelete");
        events.add("afterDelete");
        EVENTS = Collections.unmodifiableList(events);
    }

    @Autowired
    ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingRepositoryEventListener;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Validator> validators = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(Validator.class);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Validator> entry : validators.entrySet()) {
            EVENTS.stream().filter(p -> entry.getKey().startsWith(p)).findFirst()
                    .ifPresent(p -> validatingRepositoryEventListener.addValidator(p, entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a stab in the dark - I've not used `spring-data-rest`. However, after having a read of the tutorial you're following, I think the problem is that you need a `PersonValidator` not a `PeopleValidator`. Rename everything accordingly:

**PersonValidator**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class PersonValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        errors.reject("DIE");
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonValidator beforeCreatePersonValidator() {
        return new PersonValidator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But it didn't seem to make a difference. I retried it the manual way and it worked. I will have to try it again on my project when I get to work.

Comment: @Muel - how did you test it ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to use annotated handlers as specified here
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/events-chapter.html#d5e443

Here is an example of how to use annotated handlers:

```
import gr.bytecode.restapp.model.Agent;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeCreate;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeSave;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryEventHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(Agent.class)
public class AgentEventHandler {

    public static final String NEW_NAME = "**modified**";

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleBeforeCreates(Agent agent) {
            agent.setName(NEW_NAME);
    }

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleBeforeSave(Agent agent) {
        agent.setName(NEW_NAME + "..update");
    }
}
```

Example is from [github](https://github.com/dbalaouras/Spring-Data-REST-Event-Handling-Test/blob/master/src/main/java/gr/bytecode/restapp/configuration/AgentEventHandler.java) edited for brevity.

Comment: Using validators is better than the handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that spring-data-rest is built upon Spring Data PersistentEntity, it may not be easy to apply validation directly (against validation info from your model objects).

You may have to do the following to make a request validation work:

1. Create a bean validator factory to create JSR-303 bean validator if you don't have one yet:

@Configuration
public class BeanValidatorConfig {

```
@Bean
LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

}

2. Add the bean validator

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomizedRepositoryRestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

```
private final LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

@Override
public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener v) {
    v.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
    v.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
    v.addValidator("beforeLinkSave", validator);
}
```

}