# Spring - How to apply a projection on a single resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I am trying to apply a projection on an entity class called `Institute`.

I have the following projection class defined.

```
@Projection(name = "instituteProjection", types = { Institute.class })
public interface InstituteProjection {

    String getOrganizationName();

    Contact getContact();

    Address getRegisteredAddress();

    Address getMailingAddress();

}
```

I followed an answer by Oliver Gierke [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376090/how-to-apply-spring-data-projections-in-a-spring-mvc-controllers) and was able to return a collection resource with the projections when `http://localhost:8080/institutes` is called. I did this by implementing the following method in the service layer and then calling it using a REST controller.

```
@Autowired
private ProjectionFactory projectionFactory;

@Autowired
InstituteTypeRepository instituteTypeRepo;

@Override
public PagedResources<Institute> getAllInstitutes(Pageable page) {
    Page<?> instituteList = instituteRepo.findAll(page).
            map(institute -> projectionFactory.createProjection(InstituteListProjection.class, institute));
    PagedResources<Institute> instituteListPaged = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(instituteList);
    return instituteListPaged;

}
```

Now how do I apply the same projection to an item resource when `http://localhost:8080/institutes/1` is called?

**UPDATE 1:**

Controller method to get a single resource

```
@RequestMapping(value = "institutes/{instituteId}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getInstitute(@PathVariable Long instituteId) {
    Institute institute = service.getInstitute(instituteId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(institute, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Service layer method to get the single resource from the repository

```
@Override
public Institute getInstitute(Long instituteId) {
    Institute institute = instituteRepo.findOne(instituteId);
    return institute;
}
```

Comment: Did you read my answer? Did it help?

Comment: can you update question with controller logic

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear. You can expose Spring Data repositories as rest resources automatically i.e. you do not need to define your own Spring MVC controller.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#install-chapter

With SDR repositories, projections defined as 'excerpt projections' can be applied automatically to collection resources:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpts

but not to single resources. For single resources clients have to specify the required projection by means of a request parameter.

If you wanted to have a projection automatically applied to a single resource then that may be a reason for implementing your own controller (however it is unclear from your question if this is what you are doing).

For alternative means of auto applying a projection to a single resource (i.e. without a custom controller then see here):

[Spring Data REST: projection representation of single resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289665/spring-data-rest-projection-representation-of-single-resource/40291003#40291003)

If you are creating a custom controller in order to auto apply a projection then it may be possible to simple write a custom query method that returns a Projection rather than the full entity and invoke that from your controller/service:

https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods

Essentially then with a bit of configuration you could have selected Spring Data repositories automatically exposed as REST resources without having to write any controller code.

Comment: How do I call the service layer without using a custom REST controller? I know having the SDR generated controllers will save me a lot of code.

Comment: If you want to do additional processing in response to create/update/delete REST requests then you can use event handlers. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Comment: I tried doing this using SDR generated controllers earlier but this made constraint validation using annotations on entity classes throw a JPA rollback exception instead of giving a ConstraintViolationException when a constraint is not fulfilled. So I had to write manual validations in RepositoryEventHandler class which is not convenient.

Comment: You can validate in SDR just the same as in a Spring MVC Controller either using JSR303 annotations or Spring Validator implementations. I do not have the required config to hand but I'm sure there are plenty of resources around.

Comment: With a custom controller I can just add the @Valid annotation to the POST method and validate the entity, This will throw a specific ConstraintViolationException. However if I use SDR generated controllers it throws a JPA roll back exception. I wouldnt know the specific constraint which was violated. Is there a way to solve this problem

Comment: If it throws a JPA rollback exception then it sounds like the validation is not executing. If it is executig then create a @ControllerAdvice to transform the errors to a JSON response.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220440/can-jsr-303-bean-validation-be-used-with-spring-data-rest. **Ask a new question if you need further help with validation**

Comment: The validation is executing and I do see the ConstraintViolation exception in NetBeans error log. But when I am getting a RollBack exception when in PostMan

Comment: I started using SDR controllers as you suggested. The valdiations for POST is working but it still throw a rollback exception for PUT request. I asked a new question for this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917331/spring-data-rest-bean-validation-is-not-applied-to-put-method

Answer (score 0):

In your controller or @RestController you should declare a **@PathVariable**. Maybe that thread will be of service for you: [Spring mvc @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803731/spring-mvc-pathvariable)
So you implement your controller using path variable parsing and then call your service with the **PathVariable** as arguement

Comment: I already implemented the controller method to get a single resource. I will include that part in the question so you can take look. Now I am calling the service layer to get the resource through the repository. So how do I apply the projection when I get the resource from the repository?

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done in lates Spring Data Rest releases!

All you need to do is to:

1. pass projection name as request param

   ```
   `/institutes/1?projection=instituteProjection`
   ```
2. return `PersistentEntityResource` instead of `Institute` from your service method;

Done!

and I assume you want to call this service method from your custom controller, in this case you need to return `ResponseEntity<PersistentEntityResource>` from your controller method.

Spring Data Rest takes care of applying `@Projection`s to `PersistentEntityResource`s on api requests, it's just like you keep exposing your `@RestResource` from `@RepositoryRestResource`; same behaviour for projections, keeping same naming convention, basically same URI (for current example).

Your service method with a bit of bussiness logic might look like:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public PersistentEntityResource getInstitute(Long instituteId, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {
        Institute institute = instituteRepo.findOne(instituteId);
        return resourceAssembler.toModel(institute);
    }
```

and your controller method might look like this:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "institutes/{instituteId}")
    ResponseEntity<PersistentEntityResource> getInstitute(@PathVariable Long instituteId,
                                                                    PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(service.getInstitute(instituteId, resourceAssembler));
    }
}
```

spring-data-rest 3.3.4.RELEASE

also check out easier way [to return a collection resource with the projections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67971287/7849431)