# Listening repository events in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying RepositoryEventListener to work in spring-boot application but i guess im doing something wrong ...

This is the code in the Listener

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class BeforeSaveEventListener extends AbstractRepositoryEventListener {  

    @Override
    public void onBeforeSave(Object customer) {
        throw new RuntimeException("++++ BEFORE SAVE EVENT ++++");
    }
}
```

This is my Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        springApplication.addListeners(new BeforeSaveEventListener());
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
}
```

On save operation i can see these events fired:

```
Current Event is org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.BeforeCreateEvent received!
Current Event is org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.AfterCreateEvent received!
Current Event is org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletRequestHandledEvent received!
```

So no "BeforeSave" event seen ... maybe is something deprecated on documentation, or spring-boot mechanisms may be different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained here [Spring-Data-Rest Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318405/spring-data-rest-validator)

" ... it appears that the before/after "save" events only fire on PUT and PATCH. When POSTing, the before/after "create" events fire."