# Spring Boot @RepositoryEventHandler not invoked

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I've got a `@RepositoryEventHandler` set up and it is not being invoked for some unknown reason.

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(User.class)
public class UserEventHandler {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordCrypto passwordCrypto;

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleUserSave(User user) {
        if (user.getPassword() != null && !"".equals(user.getPassword())) {
            user.setPassword(passwordCrypto.encrypt(user.getPassword()));
        }
    }

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleUserCreate(User user) {
        user.setPassword(passwordCrypto.encrypt(user.getPassword()));
    }
}
```

The Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findOneByUsername(String username);
}
```

And my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("de.ihrig.feuerwehr.hydranet.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan({
    "somepath",
    "somepath including the UserEventHandler"
})
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance, I just cannot find the error.

Comment: Please can you clairfy what you mean by not working ? How are you invoking your rest service ? The same set up works for me, I believe the problem might lie in how you conclude that it is not working.

Comment: OK, I think I missunderstood the concept of @RepositoryEventHandler. It is called on the HTTP Requests done to the Data-REST exposed repositories, but not when you use any repository-method programmatically, which is what I did. The naming of the annotation is missleading somehow...

Comment: ^^ I think that is your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to listen to repository changes done programmatically?

Comment: You can just use JPA callbacks for this like `@PrePersist` if you use annotations.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a couple of things going on.

You're repo isn't annotated w/ `@RestResource`, but I'm guess that was just an oversight.

I'm guessing the comments are correct and you're testing this through a unit test with an entry point that is not going through the REST API.  The `handlers` only capture Repo events that are coming through that vector.

If you want to capture any repo event, regardless of entry point, then you want to use a `AbstractRepositoryEventListener`

The [Spring Data Rest Events documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events) covers this.  Also see [listening for repository events in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329832/listening-repository-events-in-spring-boot).

Comment: Oh, and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895854/jpa-postpersist-postupdate-transaction

Comment: _"If you want to capture any repo event, regardless of entry point, then you want to use a AbstractRepositoryEventListener"_ <-- I am not so sure. I just tested this and made an AbstractRepositoryEventListener. It is indeed triggering for my REST calls but not in my CommandLineRunner class where I initially insert some data into my database using repositories. The fact the class is in the package org.springframework.data.rest.core.event also makes it questionable.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek I think you're right. The docs are for SDR and they clearly state "_There are eight different events that the REST exporter emits _" so that indicates the events are only triggered via SPR.  

Another option might be to use [Spring Data JPA Auditing hooks](http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa) for `AuditingEntityListener` & `@Pre/@Post` annotations, but I'm not sure what baggage that might introduce.

Comment: I'm thinking you would have to intercept the call somehow, determine if it was called via the REST API or not, if it wasn't, then publish a `BeforeSaveEvent` but based on my experience w/ SDR, that seems like a dangerous proposition.  A better way might be to have an application event listener that decorates the created repo bean w/ the funcs that `UserEventHandler` is already doing. 

Or go the easy route, and override `setPassword` to always encrypt immediately.

Comment: I’m not the OP, I needed to hook into this event for another reason, but it’s not super critical in my case, I can work around it. I’ll have a look at those options though, thanks.