# how to make RepositoryEventHandler working in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler({Person.class})
public class RepositoryListener  {
@HandleBeforeDelete
public void handleEventBeforeDelete(Person person){
    java.lang.System.out.println("handleAuthorBeforeCreate");
}
@HandleAfterDelete
public void handleEventAfterDelete(Person person){
    java.lang.System.out.println("handleAuthorAfterCreate");
}
@HandleBeforeSave
public void handleEventBeforeSave(Event event){
    java.lang.System.out.println("handleAuthorBeforeSave");
}
@HandleAfterSave
public void handleEventAfterSave(Perrson person){
    java.lang.System.out.println("yulin-11 handleAuthorAfterSave");
}
@HandleBeforeCreate
public void handEventBeforeCreate(Person person){
    java.lang.System.out.println("handEventBeforeCreate");
}
@HandleAfterCreate
public void handleEventAfterCreate(Person person){
    java.lang.System.out.println("handleEventAfterCreate");
}
}
```

I create the RepositoryListener as above. When I fire delete and post rest call in the controller, it doesn't invoke any of those methods in the RepositoryListener. (Person is my domain class). Does anyone know what I am missing? thx!

Comment: Q: What is your "repository"?  For example, an Oracle 11g RDBMS?  Q: How are you "firing a delete"?  A stored procedure in a database?  Q: What version of Spring Boot are you using?  How are you running your app?  In Eclipse?  Tomcat?  On a production server?

Comment: I am using intellij maven. this is my Person Repository class: public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<person, personID> {}. I am using springboot 2.0.5.release.

Comment: Q: So how do you "fire a delete"?  What sequence of actions/events cause a "delete" to "fire"?  Does a user click something on a web page?  Is the database involved prior to Spring Boot getting called?  What exactly leads up to this "event" your controller doesn't seem to be getting?

Comment: it is an REST. I am using postman localhost:8080/person/id, choose delete option to fire the controller.

Comment: Got it.  So the problem has nothing to do with the database: you're using Postman to invoke your Spring Boot API.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) [Enable verbose trace logging](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging), 2) [Use your IntelliJ debugger](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring/remote-debug-spring-boot-application-with-maven-and-intellij/)

Comment: the problem is the RepositoryListener class has never been called.

Comment: have you tried to use `@RepositoryEventHandler(Person.class)`? Also, you don't have to declare your class as a `@Component`

Comment: We get that "the RepositoryListener class has never been called".  Now we need to figure out WHY.  One way is to "guess", and "try stuff".  A *BETTER* way is to try to get more information to analyze the problem.  Trace logging is one tool that could help; a good debugger is another tool  Please consider trying them.

Answer (score 0):

Check that comment below most probably it the answer, I didn't try it myself

> It is called on the HTTP Requests done to the Data-REST exposed
> repositories, but not when you use any repository-method
> programmatically

link mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796049/spring-boot-repositoryeventhandler-not-invoked)