# Exceptions with Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-data-rest

I'm starting on the concepts of microservices with *Springboot* and *Spring Data Rest* for me is very confusing how can I do with a few lines of code. 
My main question is: I just have entities and repositories, the Spring Data Rest "generates" paths for all the POST requests, GET etc. and my repository performs correctly. 
But how do exception handling?
 For example, I send a POST without the "name" field and this is accepted **but I want to return an error**. How do I do that?

Entity

```
@Document
public class Veiculo{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String nome;
    private String tipo;
    @DBRef
    List<Contato> contatos;

    @DBRef
    List<Cliente> clientes;


    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public Veiculo setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public Veiculo setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        return this;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return this.tipo;
    }

    public Veiculo setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
        return this;
    }

    public List<Contato> getContatos() {
        return this.contatos;
    }

    public Veiculo setContatos(List<Contato> contatos) {
        this.contatos = contatos;
        return this;
    }

    public List<Cliente> getClientes() {
        return this.clientes;
    }

    public Veiculo setClientes(List<Cliente> clientes) {
        this.clientes = clientes;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "veiculos", path = "veiculos")
public interface VeiculoRepository extends MongoRepository<Veiculo, String> {
    Veiculo save(Veiculo veiculo);

    List<Veiculo> findAll();

}
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318405/spring-data-rest-validator) talks about validating requests with Spring Data Rest. Is it something you are looking for?

Comment: Wow perfect! But I need a example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just apply javax.validation.constraints.NotNull to the name parameter? Spring Data REST will apply the validation check and fail if the value is missing.